# PHP json_encode extra quote before array square bracket

Tags: php, json

I intend to generate JSON that's like this:

{
"stores": [{"Name":"abc","Phone","1234567"},{"Name":"def","Phone","1111111"}],
"numResults": 2
}

My php code is like this:

```
       while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $store[] = $row;
            $k++;
       }
       $obj['stores'] = json_encode($store);           
       $obj['numResult'] = $numResult;           
       echo stripslashes(json_encode($obj));
```

However the result seems to have an extra pair of double quotes around the square brackets:

{
"stores": "[{"Name":"abc","Phone","1234567"},{"Name":"def","Phone","1111111"}]",
"numResults": 2
}

How can I remove them? (Or is what's actually showing suppose to be the correct JSON formatting?)

Thanks!

Comment: You remove them by not adding them ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only convert to JSON one time, once you have the complete object the way you want it:

```
       while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $store[] = $row;
            $k++;
       }
       $obj['stores'] = $store; // <---------Note change           
       $obj['numResult'] = $numResult;           
       $myJSONstring = json_encode($obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You wont need to json_encode twice. Create your `$obj` variable and json_encode that once it is completely created.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way would be

```
$my_string = json_encode($my_json,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```